# Understanding the statistics of VS load test

Tags: asp.net, load, performance-testing, load-testing

Recently i have created a web performance test and load test using vs2010. I have run the test  and got the results. Having little trouble in understating the statistics. Haven't found sufficient material online to make understand and analyze the test results.

small snapshot of the results
[image]

> > Avg page time:1.29s & 
> >     Avg Response time:0.41s

**This tests i have ran for 250 virtual users with step load**

- What can i understand from 95% of pagetime
- My appserver cpu usage is around 85% is that bad ?

Answer (score 1):

"95% page time" is short hand for the "95th percentile of page times", meaning that 95% of them completed within that time, only 5% of them took longer than that time. Other parts of the test results will contain the 90%, 95% and 99% percentile values.

For the server CPU usage, only you and the system designers can tell what is a good value. Is the load applied during the test realistic of real usage both in range of activities performed and in total user load? Is the server intended to handle a bigger load? Are the activities performed by the server complex and CPU demanding? If your load test is at the extreme (high) end of expected loads then the 85% may be quite reasonable. I have seen values of maximum server loads specified to be from 50% to 90% depending on the system and its architecture. As well as average CPU load you should examine the peaks, if it holds steady at, or very close to, 100% for long enough to see a flat top to the usage graph then your CPU is limiting system performance. If it just touches 100% occasionally then that may be OK, but again check with the system designers.